# sending an email via Pony mail with no authentication?

Tags: ruby

I want to send an email from my ruby script using Pony mail. When I set it up for gmail smtp it works fine. When I set it up to use our ISP's SMPT I get this error.

I was told by iiNet representative that no authentication is needed. When I send email from command line using mail command it works nicely. Or even when sending email using `telnet mail.iinet.com.au 25` no authentication is required.

`/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:777:in check_auth_args': SMTP-AUTH requested but missing secret phrase (ArgumentError)`

for settings

```
  Pony.mail(:to => 'radek@edume.com.au', 
        :from => 'radek@edu.com.au',
            :subject => 'overnight testing results', 
            :body => results, 
            :via => :smtp, 
            :via_options => {
               #:openssl_verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
               :address     => 'mail.iinet.com.au',
               :port     => '25',
               #:enable_starttls_auto => true,
               #:user_name     => 'qwer@mail.iinet.com.au',
               #:password => '1234',
               :authentication     => :plain,           # :plain, :login, :cram_md5, no auth by default
                :domain               => "localhost.localdomain" # the HELO domain provided by the client to the server
                                                     }
)
```

### conf

- ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel (249) [x86_64-linux]
- mail (2.3.0)
- mime-types (1.16)
- pony (1.2)

## update I

if I do telnet `mail.iinet.com.au 25` with below commands the email is sent and received. No authentication required.

```
mail from: from@address
rcpt to: to@address
data
from: from@address
to: to@address
subject: subject line
message body
.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted a question to ponyrb group and the solution is to use `enable_starttls_auto => false`

so the final working code for me is

```
Pony.mail(
  :to => 'radek@edu.com.au', 
  :from => 'radek@edu.com.au',
  :subject => 'test', 
  :body => "test pony", 
  :via => :smtp, 
  :via_options => {
      :address     => 'mail.iinet.com.au',
      :port     => '25',
      :enable_starttls_auto => false
    }
)
```

Answer (score 5):

You are specifying that you want to perform authentication.  Remove the line that says `:authentication => :plain`

Comment: I tried that before posting my question but I got `/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:777:in `check_auth_args': SMTP-AUTH requested but missing secret phrase (ArgumentError)
`

Answer (score 3):

This works like a charm for me:

```
require 'pony'

Pony.mail(
  :to => 'xxx', 
  :from => 'xxx',
  :subject => 'test', 
  :body => "test", 
  :via => :smtp, 
  :via_options => {
      :address     => 'xxx',
      :port     => '25',
    }
)
```

obviously you need to replace these "xxx" with real values

Comment: /usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/openssl/ssl-internal.rb:123:in `post_connection_check': hostname was not match with the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mail-2.3.0/lib/mail/core_extensions/smtp.rb:17:in `tlsconnect'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:562:in `do_start'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:525:in `start'

Comment: from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mail-2.3.0/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:128:in `deliver!'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mail-2.3.0/lib/mail/message.rb:245:in `deliver!'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pony-1.2/lib/pony.rb:165:in `deliver'
 from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pony-1.2/lib/pony.rb:137:in `mail'

Comment: You can try with port 465 which is the port for smtp with ssl, maybe your host is requiring ssl even without authentication.

Comment: no, mail.iinet.com.au doesn't require authentication. I managed to send email using `net/smtp` ruby library only.

Comment: I understand that no authentication is required but still, did you tried my code above with port 465 ? It does not cost much to try ;)

Comment: the same error `/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/openssl/ssl-internal.rb:123:in `post_connection_check': hostname was not match with the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)` + I updated my question. See update I

Comment: Here is something else you can try since a direct telnet works: in one terminal start a network sniffer ngrep or tcpdump will do the trick, here is the command for ngrep: ngrep -Tpd eth0 port 25 . With that in place run your ruby script, it may gives you some clues to understand what is really sent/received from the smtp server.